# Kony Studio Android app onRowClick not firing on iOS iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, temenos-quantum

We have Kony app which uses an onRowClick event to highlight and un-highlight a row in a segment. Our onRowClick fires correctly in Android and fires correctly most of the time on iOS.

THE ISSUE WE ARE HAVING is when the page first opens we have the first row selected and if you click on the first row to un-highlight it, the onRowClick event does not get executed. If you click on any row besides the first one, the onRowClick event executes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We are running in the Kony Studio emulator on our iMac. Emulater is set to

Comment: We are running on the Kony Studio emulator on our iMac. It is set to iPhone 6 running iOS 8.3

Comment: It's rather hard to say without looking at code/ methodology you've used to implement this selecting and deselecting.... Are you using a flag?